# Calculating the sum of quantity for N rows with week number which fall under range of weeks in the current row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has columns *categoryA*, *categoryB*, *year*, *month*, *week* and the *quantity* corresponding to a specific value.

I want to find the sum of the *quantity* values for past 12 weeks for that particular category combination.

I tried the below code

**query 1**

```
select
    categoryA
    , categoryB
    , year
    , month
    , week
    , SUM(quantity) OVER 
            PARTITION BY(categoryA, categoryB 
            ORDER BY categoryA, categoryB, year, month, week rows BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
FROM TABLE1
```

But the issue is there might be gaps in the week for example *Year 2020* may not have row for week 20 in that case the *quantity* for that row has to be considered 0.

I tried generating the range of weeks between which *quantity* has to be summed for each row like this:

**query 2**

```
SELECT year,week, month, categoryA, categoryB,
                        CASE WHEN week> 12 THEN week- 12
                             WHEN week= 1 THEN 0
                             ELSE 1 END AS startWeek1,
                        CASE WHEN week<> 1 THEN week- 1
                             WHEN week= 1 THEN 0 END AS endWeek1,

                        CASE WHEN week<> 1 THEN year
                             ELSE 0 END AS startYear, 
                        CASE WHEN week> 12 THEN 0
                             ELSE year- 1 END AS EndYear,

                        CASE WHEN week> 12 THEN 0
                             ELSE datepart(week, DATEFROMPARTS(year -1, 12, 31)) - (12 - week) END AS startWeek2,
                        CASE WHEN week > 12 THEN 0
                             ELSE datepart(week, DATEFROMPARTS(year-1, 12, 31)) END AS endWeek2
```

But now I have to somehow compare whether the last 12 rows fall under the range of weeks and years specified in current row in my **query 1**

Please note that I was able to implement the solution by using UDF, but the performance was horrible since I had to call it for each row.

My table has data something like this:

```
year   month  week  categoryA  categoryB  quantity
2020   1      1     steel      white      2
2020   1      2     steel      white      4
2020   2      5     steel      white      5
2020   2      6     steel      white      1
2020   10     40    steel      white      1
2020   10     41    steel      white      10
```

Expected Result:

```
year   month  week  categoryA  categoryB  quantity  lastTwelveWeeksQuantity
2020   1      1     steel      white      2          0
2020   1      2     steel      white      4          2
2020   2      5     steel      white      5          6
2020   2      6     steel      white      1          11 
2020   10     40    steel      white      1          0
2020   10     41    steel      white      10         1
```

**EDIT**
**Another use case with weeks spanning across years and has to be group by categoryA and categoryB**

```
 year   month  week  categoryA  categoryB  quantity
    2019   12     43    steel      white      2
    2020   1      1     steel      white      2
    2020   1      2     steel      white      4
    2020   2      5     steel      white      5
    2020   2      6     steel      white      1
    2020   10     40    steel      white      1
    2020   10     41    steel      white      10
```

Expected Result:

```
year   month  week  categoryA  categoryB  quantity  lastTwelveWeeksQuantity
2019   12     43    steel      white      2         0
2019   12     53    steel      blue       2         0
2020   1      1     steel      white      2         2 
2020   1      2     steel      white      4         4(considering quantity from 2019 as it falls in range for last 12 weeks i,e week 1 in 2020 and week 53 to 43 in 2019) 
2020   2      5     steel      white      5         6
2020   2      6     steel      white      1         11
2020   10     40    steel      white      1         0
2020   10     41    steel      white      10        1
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results (**not** images) will help us help you here.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, I have added some example data and result

Answer (score 0):

Here you have, use a sub-query.

```
create table #exampleStack(anio numeric,mes numeric,semana numeric,categoryA varchar(50),categoryB varchar(50),quantity numeric)

INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','1 ','1 ','steel','white','2')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','1 ','2 ','steel','white','4')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','2 ','5 ','steel','white','5')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','2 ','6 ','steel','white','1')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','10','40','steel','white','1')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','10','41','steel','white','10')

SELECT 
A.anio,A.mes,A.semana,A.categoryA,A.categoryB,A.quantity
,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(quantity),0) FROM #exampleStack WHERE anio<=A.anio and mes<=A.mes  and semana>=A.semana-13 and semana<A.semana)
FROM #exampleStack AS A
```

Comment: Hi @MrKino this works great if weeks are in a single year, thank you. But I have data with weeks spanning across years, just updated my question with the scenario, sorry missed to add it before.Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to arrive at this answer by enhancing @MrKnino 's solution, to cover scenario with weeks spanning across years.
**But the performance is very bad, I have 800000 rows and it is taking more than an hour for execution probably since subquery has to be run for each row**

```
    create table #exampleStack(anio numeric,mes numeric,semana numeric,categoryA varchar(50),categoryB varchar(50),quantity numeric)

INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2019','12 ','43 ','steel','white','2')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2019','12 ','53 ','steel','blue','2')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','1 ','1 ','steel','white','2')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','1 ','2 ','steel','white','4')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','2 ','5 ','steel','white','5')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','2 ','6 ','steel','white','1')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','10','40','steel','white','1')
INSERT INTO #exampleStack VALUES('2020','10','41','steel','white','10')

SELECT 
A.anio,A.mes,A.semana,A.categoryA,A.categoryB,A.quantity
,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(quantity),0) 
 FROM #exampleStack 
WHERE ( categoryB = A.categoryB AND categoryA = A.categoryA AND anio = A.anio and semana >= A.semana-12 and semana < A.semana) OR (anio = A.anio - 1 and 
semana >= datepart(week, DATEFROMPARTS(anio -1, 12, 31)) - (12 - A.semana) and semana <= datepart(week, DATEFROMPARTS(anio -1, 12, 31))) )
FROM #exampleStack AS A
```